# Android Listview combined with textView fields

Tags: android, listview, orientation

i have some issues to get by.

In portrait orientation i need simple listView with individual button for each row.
In landscape orientation i need to divide view for two areas. First (let's say at left) is ListView mentioned before. Second area contains few TextViews filled after clicking on ListView.

Questions:

1. To differ between land and portrait orientation i'm going to use layout-land and layout-port folders. But in lanscape orientation there will be few additional controls. Checking orientation in onCreate method and not initializing additional controls will be enough?
2. How to get described above landscape orientation view?

Thakns in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it the way you mentioned. Another possibility is to include all of the elements in both layouts, but in the portrait orientation you can hide some of them (by setting width/height to 0, or by setting [android:visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) to 2 (gone)).
2. You can use a horizontal LinearLayout to get two side-by-side regions. The first child of the LinearLayout will be your ListView. The second child of the LinearLayout can contain the extra TextViews you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need not check orientation in onCreate method as because android operating system will load entire activity when the orientation changes.

you need to do only one thing. for the `UI` give same id's in both landscape and portrait xml files.that's enough

Answer (score 0):

I think that the use of Fragments is fit for the layout you want to achieve.
Here is a link to a tutorial that you may find useful.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: It seems to be perfect, but in this project I'm limited to Android 2.1.